# Скрипт изменения классов при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Верстая сайт понадобилось написать скрипт,который би изменял стили  `header` при скролле,то есть если `header` находится над темной `section` то его `class` меняется на `header.white` если над светлой то `header.black`.
Что б знать секция темная или светлая для примера добавил атрибут `data-black`.

Вот что у меня получилось:

С начала взял два массива,со значениями offsetTop и высоты секции.
Если сложить  ети два  значения то получим отрезки которые занимают темные секции.

Вопрос: как зная позицию скрола,и параметры отрезков сделать:так если скролл попадает на отрезок,`header` меняет свой класс???

[Код на Codepen](https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/yPYNPK)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


  var whiteMenu = jQuery("section[data-black]");


  var sectionsHeigt = [];
  var sectionsOffset = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < whiteMenu.length; i++) {

    sectionsHeigt.push(whiteMenu[i].clientHeight);
    sectionsOffset.push(whiteMenu[i].offsetTop);

  }

  //console.log(sectionsHeigt);
  // console.log(sectionsOffset);


  function onScroll(event) {

    var scrollPos = jQuery(document).scrollTop();



    // здесь должна бить магия


    if (sectionsOffset[i] + sectionsHeigt[i] > scrollPos) {
      //  console.log('menu white');
    } else {
      // console.log('menu black');
    }



  }

  jQuery(document).on("scroll", onScroll);


});
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

header.white {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

header.black {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#section_1 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 700px;
}

#section_2 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 800px;
}

#section_3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 600px;
}

#section_4 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 500px;
}

#section_5 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 800px;
}

footer {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header class='white'>
    <h2>header</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="section_1"></section>
    <section id="section_2" data-black></section>
    <section id="section_3"></section>
    <section id="section_4" data-black></section>
    <section id="section_5"></section>
  </main>
  <footer data-black></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ищем отступ экрана

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()+header.height();
```

Бежим по section.

Для каждой узнаем отступы границ блока от верха страницы.

Если отступ экрана находится между этими значениями - значит header находится на этом блоке.

```
sections.each(function(){
  var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top,
      offsetBottom = offsetTop + $(this).height();
  if (offsetTop <= scrollTop && offsetBottom >= scrollTop) {
      header.attr('class', headerClasses[+$(this).is('.black')]);
      return false;
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skywave/phL0hy97/3/

Comment: Все оказалось проще чем я думал, спасибо вам!